# Using Symfony with Backbone.js

Tags: php, javascript, symfony

I wanted to get views from the symfony community about how one would achieve using `backbone.js` to create a one paged application.
Is it even possible to call the functions in symfony (e.g public function executeCreate()) through backbone.js) has anyone done it?
Can you give me some resources? thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course you cannot directly access a php method through javascript (client vs. server). You would have to provide a API of some kind (REST anyone?) which the js could use to access and post data.

Answer (score 2):

Why not? Symfony easily can return JSON data on request by backbone clientside app. For Symfony2 it can be like this:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyController extends Controller {
    public function createAction($requestParam1, $requestParam2)
        $response = new Response(json_encode(array(
            'requestParam1' => $requestParam1,
            'requestParam2' => $requestParam2
        )));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy Chekalyuk and what about the next step? I mean probably I have to rewrite Backbone.sync in order to get these data?

Comment: @user1331126 If you need some other persistence strategy than default RESTful ajax request, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to have a look at the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle). Another attempt could be to handle the requests yourself, and return the date from the orm/odm via [Serializer](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle)

the only thing bothered me so far, was the form handling (used [backbone-forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms)), where I simply not was able to keep my code DRY (had duplicate data for the form+validation in symfony and in the frontend-part).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start a new Symfony2 + backbone app, I would recommend this bundle:

https://github.com/gigo6000/DevtimeBackboneBundle

There's also a demo app that can be helpful to see the backbone.js and Symfony2 interaction:

https://github.com/gigo6000/DevtimeRafflerBundle